# Is there any significance in Mr. Tanaka's chibified form?

Tags: black-butler

In Kuroshitsuji, most of the time Mr. Tanaka is drawn in chibified form and says nothing but "ho ho ho". At certain times, however, he reverts back to his normal form for a short amount of time, like when he returned to his former rank of head butler following Sebastian's absence. Is there any significance to this? Does it has any meaning for the story?

Edit: I mean like how Finny was a kaizo-ningen (he underwent an operation to gain inhuman strength) or how Mei Rin was an assassin and Bard was a soldier.

Comment: This is just my perception but for one comedy, and for two intensity. It's always funny to see "cute little Tanaka-san" sitting and drinking his tea and frankly, it always makes me smile. Maybe there is a reason as to why he is usually in chibi mode since they've said he has a time limit to being in normal mode. For the intensity part, if you've noticed, he only reverts to his normal state in serious or significant moments in the series, so when we see him that way we know that a) this is a really significant moment or b) it's about to go down.

Comment: In episode 1 or 2 there's a short explanation by Finn but I didn't quite remember it although it had something to do with hot or cold.